# VIdeo with 24 fps and 1/50 shutter speed settings - where have the "redundant" frames gone?

Tags: shutter-speed, video, framerate

Just delved into the photo, video science and stuck at this point.
Ok, there is a recommendation:

> It is suggested that you double the FPS to get your working shutter speed, so when shooting at 24 FPS, use at least 1/50 of a second shutter speed and when shooting at 30 FPS, use at least 1/60 of a second shutter speed.

But if we shoot with 1/50 shutter speed, don't we end up with 50 frames for every second? And then, if we have to arrange only 24 frames into a second timeframe, don't we have to drop out about every second frame?

Comment: No, you just take a frame with 1/50 speed. Walking I can take one photo per hour with 1/8000.

Comment: I think what you are asking about is called shutter angle in videography, and yes there is a separate stack exchange for videography exactly because terminology and practices are so different between photo and video applications...

Comment: @RomeoNinov in other words, I do the same number of frames (24 pcs of them) no matter how quckly I expose that particular frame to light? That leads me to another question, why then bother with "24fps > 1/50, 30fps > 1/60" rule, why not just use 1/50 for both? What's wrong with 1/50 for 30fps?

Comment: @AndrewAnderson the main point here is *why don't you ask your question on https://video.stackexchange.com/*? That said, doing a quick search on the web reveals a whole lot of tutorials and other literature on the topic of the *180° shutter rule*.

Comment: @AndrewAnderson, the reason is 180 degrees (1/50, 24/25 FPS) shutter angle give smooth and natural looking movement in the video.

Comment: @MrUpsidown, I'll do! Thanks to the comments here, including yours, I've learnt what to google now.  I have never imagined such things as "shutter angle", etc. That said, there's a chance I will find my questions asked with a new googling.